# openldap synchronous vs. asynchronous replication

Tags: openldap

I've installed two openldap servers and configured them to do replication via 'syncrepl'.  This replication is however **asychronous**. Changes are not immediately written to the other ldap server. What I would like to do is **synchronous** replication. With new or updated entries only written to the primary LDAP after they have been written to the second LDAP server.

Does anybody know if this is possible with openLDAP?

Comment: There are about 24 combinations of options for the `syncrepl` overlay. Not all of them make sense, but it is certainly possible to do exactly as you describe, using `refreshAndPersist` connections from the slave(s). Off topic.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided your syncrepl configuration.